# Props with same object name on multiple pages of website

Tags: reactjs

I trying to understand how exactly react keep the data from Props.

My example is:

1. I open page 1 and get props with Automat objects.
2. I go to the page 2 with too get props with Automat objects, but they are diffrent (other action).

Problem is when I go to page 2, or any other, the props from first page still exists and my data is wrong. In this situation the only way to get rid of them is refresh of page or calling a function but this is a wrong way. In this situation I should somehow first remove a page 1 Automat Props, or maybe on each page call get Props with unique name (but this is non sense I think)?

I get data from Java (SpringBoot) and Hibernate.

page 1

////// get all automats - return list of all automats in database

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAutomats();
  }


export const getAutomats = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/automat/all");
  dispatch({
    type: GET_AUTOMATS, //typ reducera
    payload: res.data, //dane z bazy
  });
};
```

json example

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "zimny jeden",
        "serialNumber": "123456",
        "type": "2",
        "deleted": 0,
        "status": null,
        "productionDate": null,
        "fundsDrawns": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "",
        "serialNumber": "",
        "type": "Zimny",
        "deleted": 0,
        "status": null,
        "productionDate": "2021-00-08",
        "fundsDrawns": []
    }
]
```

then go to page 2

////// get all automats whose not used

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getAutomatFree();
      }


export const getAutomatFree = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/automat/all/free");
  dispatch({
    type: GET_AUTOMATS, //typ reducera
    payload: res.data, //dane z bazy
  });
};
```

json example

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "zimny jeden",
        "serialNumber": "123456",
        "type": "2",
        "deleted": 0,
        "status": null,
        "productionDate": null,
        "fundsDrawns": []
    }
]
```

Both pages return props with Objects type Automats, but when I go from page 1 to page 2, I see two or even three Automats (sum of page 1 and page 2) instead of one.

Edit: reducer

```
    import { GET_AUTOMAT, GET_AUTOMATS, DELETE_AUTOMAT } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  automats: [], //array
  automat: {} //single
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_AUTOMATS:
      //...state - Adds old state properties to the new object by copying
      return {
        ...state,
        automats: action.payload // dane z listą projektów, które zaktualizują state
      };

    case GET_AUTOMAT:
      return {
        ...state,
        automat: action.payload
      };

    case DELETE_AUTOMAT:
      return {
        //jeżeli delete się uda to ma odświeżyć poprzez odfiltrowanie usuniętego obiektu
        //zwraca do wyswietlenia projekty sprzeczne z action.payload (id do skasowania)
        ...state,
        automats: state.automats.filter(
          automat => automat.serialNumber !== action.payload
        )
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide any code samples, it is really hard to understand what is the problem exactly.

Comment: Hi, can you also share your reducer's code sample?